# Powershell Visible Progress while running processes

Tags: powershell, progress

I got my powershell script finished and it does perfectly what it should do. But for the useres of the script its kinda a mess. For the real testing from my side it was just perfect but now all they need is to see the progess.

I got some ideas and have seen a lot of options but I can't get something to work.

In my opinion the best would be if they can see the Progress and what is happening behind.
My best solution so far is this.

```
#$i++
#$intLength = rows in csv     I don't know how to get this 
#Write-Host "Processing ..."
#Write-Host " $i done of $intLength"
```

so this should be on the top in powershell and below this should go through

```
foreach($n in $y)
{ 
    try 
        {
        $Computer = [system.net.dns]::resolve($n.$Filter) | Select HostName,AddressList
        $IP = ($Computer.AddressList).IPAddressToString
        Write-Host $n.$Filter $IP
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{IPAddress=$IP; $colname=$n.$Filter} | Export-Csv $Saveworking -NoTypeInformation -Append
        } 
    catch 
        {
        Write-Host "$($n.$Filter) is unreachable."
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{$colname=$n.$Filter} | Export-Csv $SaveFailed -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
}
```

Is there a way to "prioritize" so this from above is runing fine and seen the whole progress even when there are about 600 lines running through?

If needed I can hand over the full script for reproduction as well.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Im not really sure what your asking but maybe **write-progress** would be a good start for what your looking for

Comment: Hey Kevin, I agree with ArcSet.. Write-Progess would be a good place to start. I can't really grasp what you're asking us for? Something i've done in the past (a little more complicated than using write-process) is to start a task as a job, and then do a while loop to look at `$Job.JobStateInfo.State -eq "Running"` and while its running you can check on how much it's progressed and somehow output that information.

Comment: but isn't the write-progress only this progressbar ?